# Complex number in python

Tags: python, matlab, complex-numbers

How to write a complex number in python? Indeed I have:

```
import math
a=3
b=4
function=a*j*x+b*y
```

I don't want to write directly 3j in my function since I absolutely want to use a, so how to convert a into a complex number? Cause in matlab it works when printing :

```
a=3
b=a*i
```

The result will gave: `0 + 3.0000i`

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: If you want to use `j` as a complex number, you need `1j`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`j` alone is a variable, you can have the complex number by typing `1j`

```
>>> type(j)
NameError: name 'j' is not defined
>>> type(1j)
<type 'complex'>
```

So your code can be written as a function as

```
def function(x, y):
    a = 3
    b = 4
    return a*1j*x+b*y
```

Comment: This [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73361181/1176573)!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the  [`complex`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#complex) function to create a complex number from variables:

```
>>> a = 3
>>> b = 4
>>> complex(a, b)
(3+4j)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Python's Built in **complex()** function

```
>>> first_number = 10
>>> second_number = 15
>>> complex(first_number, second_number)
(10+15j)
```