# How can I use "e" (Euler's number) and power operation?

Tags: python, math, exp

How can I write `1-e^(-value1^2/2*value2^2)` in Python?

I don't know how to use power operator and `e`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.exp

Comment: Did you import Math package? And read how to use it?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use [**`exp(x)`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.exp) function of [math](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html) library, which is same as `e^x`. Hence you may write your code as:

```
import math
x.append(1 - math.exp( -0.5 * (value1*value2)**2))
```

I have modified the equation by replacing `1/2` as `0.5`. Else for Python *<2.7*, we'll have to explicitly type cast the division value to `float` because Python round of the result of division of two `int` as integer. For example: `1/2` gives `0` in python 2.7 and below.

Answer (score 22):

Just saying: `numpy` has this too. So no need to import `math` if you already did `import numpy as np`:

```
>>> np.exp(1)
2.718281828459045
```

Comment: The Numpy version has the advantage of using vectorisation when using Numpy arrays.

Answer (score 21):

Python's power operator is `**` and Euler's number is `math.e`, so:

```
 from math import e
 x.append(1-e**(-value1**2/2*value2**2))
```

Comment: You should use `math.exp(stuff)` in preference to `math.e**stuff`. It's likely to be both more accurate and faster.

Answer (score 6):

Power is `**` and `e^` is `math.exp`:

```
x.append(1 - math.exp(-0.5 * (value1*value2)**2))
```

Answer (score 3):

`math.e`      or `from math import e`  (= 2.718281…)

The two expressions `math.exp(x)` and `e**x` are equivalent
however:
Return e raised to the power x, where e = 2.718281… is the base of natural logarithms. This is usually more accurate than `math.e ** x` or `pow(math.e, x)`. [docs.python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html)

for power use `**` (`3**2` = 9),  not " ^ "
" ^ " is a bitwise XOR operator (& and, | or), it works logicaly with bits.
So for example `10^4`=14 (maybe unexpectedly) → consider the bitwise depiction:

(0000 1010 ^ 0000 0100 = 0000 1110)  [programiz](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/operators)

Answer (score 2):

Just to add, `numpy` also has `np.e`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the exponent happens to be complex number with angle expressed in *radians*. So my approach was:

```py
import cmath 
theta = cmath.pi/4
output = cmath.exp(theta*1j)   # LaTeX: $e^{i\theta}$ 
print(output)                  # (0.7071067811865476+0.7071067811865476j)
```

Note: Use `1j` instead of `j` since python throws `NameError` for `j`. And used `cmath` instead of `math`.