# How do I get the number `(0 + infj)` in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, complex-numbers

I'm using Python 3.9.15 and trying to get the number `(0 + infj)`, i.e. the imaginary part is infinite and the real part is zero.
However, I tried several alternatives but all of them gave `(nan + infj)` instead of `(0 + infj)`.

```py
>>> float('inf') * 1j
(nan+infj)
>>> float('inf') * 1j + 0
(nan+infj)
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.inf * 1j
(nan+infj)
>>> np.inf * 1j + 0
(nan+infj)
```

How do I get the number `(0 + infj)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Complex number in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572909/complex-number-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can use built-in `complex` function:

```
complex(0,float('inf'))
```